# Installed python tool qrcode not found (qr: command not found)?

Tags: python, pip, qr-code

> Noams-MacBook-Pro:folder noam$ sudo -H python -m pip install qrcode
> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
> 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python
> 2.7. Requirement already satisfied: qrcode in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (6.1) Requirement already satisfied:
> six in /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
> (from qrcode) (1.4.1)

and then

> Noams-MacBook-Pro:folder noam$ qr
>
> -bash: qr: command not found
>
> Noams-MacBook-Pro:folder noam$ qrcode
>
> -bash: qrcode: command not found

EDIT:

```
pip show --files qrcode
```

shows:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Name: qrcode
Version: 6.1
Summary: QR Code image generator
Home-page: https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode
Author: Lincoln Loop
Author-email: info@lincolnloop.com
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requires: six
Required-by: 
Files:
  qrcode-6.1.data/data/share/man/man1/qr.1
  qrcode-6.1.dist-info/LICENSE
  qrcode-6.1.dist-info/METADATA
  qrcode-6.1.dist-info/RECORD
  qrcode-6.1.dist-info/WHEEL
  qrcode-6.1.dist-info/entry_points.txt
  qrcode-6.1.dist-info/top_level.txt
  qrcode/LUT.py
  qrcode/__init__.py
  qrcode/base.py
  qrcode/console_scripts.py
  qrcode/constants.py
  qrcode/exceptions.py
  qrcode/image/__init__.py
  qrcode/image/base.py
  qrcode/image/pil.py
  qrcode/image/pure.py
  qrcode/image/svg.py
  qrcode/main.py
  qrcode/release.py
  qrcode/tests/__init__.py
  qrcode/tests/svg.py
  qrcode/tests/test_example.py
  qrcode/tests/test_qrcode.py
  qrcode/tests/test_release.py
  qrcode/tests/test_script.py
  qrcode/util.py
```

Comment: `pip show --files qrcode`

Comment: @phd please see EDIT field in original post

Comment: It must install [script `qr`](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode/blob/92e3f59be274899fb3c0c09de3c8e0b2213eb181/setup.cfg#L46) somewhere in a `bin/` directory. For me `pip show` shows `../../../bin/qr`. Try to uninstall and reinstall qrcode.